# Load Grouped Product by custom attribute

Tags: grouped-products

I need to get a grouped product url. How can I load a grouped product by a custom attribute and get its url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute_code','your_value')
    ->addUrlRewrite();

$product = $collection->getFirstItem();

if($product->getId()) {
    $product->getProductUrl();  
}
```

**OR**

```
if($product->getId()) {
    $product->getUrl(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a collection to load a product collection, filter by your attribute and then get the url.

```
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute','value')
->addUrlRewrite()
->getFirst()

$product->getUrl()
```

Afaik you can add a categoryId as parameter to `addUrlRewrite` if you want a special url.

Comment: getFirst() is giving error @Fabian Blechschmidt

Comment: check the collection mit be getFirstItem or something alike